# how to make short url when retweet in gem twitter rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I tried this gem: https://github.com/intridea/tweet-button for retweeting articles from my app. How can I change this url to the short url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bitly` gem for URL shortening, link to the gem is

https://github.com/philnash/bitly